All pain and suffering are because of karma, so it is in my destiny to suffer, but what happens if i dont suffer?
Suppose something terrible happens(death of my beloved pet), now this will cause me pain which is result of bad karma, but what if I maintain my neutral state and chose not to suffer? and treat it just like a normal incident?
does the bad karma get negated or it stays the same and pain comes in a different form?
EX: I know its not as simple as this but for the sake of my understanding:
If I suffer , New Bad karma = Previous Bad karma - X;
Now this is normal right? the basic
Case 1: I didn't suffer, New Bad Karma = Previous Bad karma , since I didn't suffer and the pain didn't cause any change .
Case 2: I didn't suffer, New Bad karma = Previous Bad karma - X, my own pain and suffering has nothing to do with scales of karma
Will it be case 1 or 2?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
